# Magic Wand equivalent

Tags: arcmap

Is there any analog in ArcGIS Desktop (10.6) of Photoshop's magic wand tool? I have a raster layer that has clearly defined polygons is there any tool that is able to click to select the areas and create a polygon from them?

[image: Polygons from raster layer]
[image: Ideal result of tool]

Also if this is not possible is it possible to write and add a tool that is able to actively be used or can you only implement scripts via creating custom geoprocessing tools?

Comment: The ArcScan extension can perform Raster-to-Vector conversion.